# Why isn't my image displaying in my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am storing images as byte arrays inside a SQL database.

Here is my Index method (inside the controller):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = db.UserProfiles.ToList();

    Dictionary<int, ActionResult> picture = list.ToDictionary(item => item.CarID, item => CarPic(item.Picture));

    ViewBag.CarPictures = picture;

    return View(list);
}
```

Here is my CarPic method:

```
public ActionResult CarPic(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    return imageBytes == null ? null : File(imageBytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Here is how I am trying to display the image inside my view:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <img src="@ViewBag.CarPictures[item.CarID]"/>
}
```

This is what shows up in the web browser:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of Intellisense:

[image: Intellisense]

So **Picture** is not null, it is a byte array. The image itself is a JPEG. Here is the code I am using to convert the image to a byte array to store it in the database:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Stock stock, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        if (file.ContentType.Contains("image"))
        {
            using (var inputStream = file.InputStream)
            {
                var memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
                if (memoryStream == null)
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }

                var data = memoryStream.ToArray();

                stock.Picture = data;
            }
        }
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserProfiles.Add(stock);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(stock);
}
```

I have checked the Database and the field is indeed populated. Here is my Stock model:

```
[Table("Stock")]
public class Stock
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    //etc etc
}
```

I am tearing my hair out here trying to work out why this isn't working, as I think I have done everything right. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the `<img>` tag.

`<img src="..." />` allows you to display an image **from a URL**.
The `src` attribute must specify a URL that returns the actual image.

If you want to embed the image in the page, you can use a `data:` URI.

Comment: Thankyou, could you possibly post a link on how to use the `data:` URI, I'm new to Razor and HTML

Comment: `src="data:image/png;base64,<Base64 data>"`

Comment: Perfect thanks, didn't think wikipedia would have samples, now I know! Thanks very much.